# Deploying secrets to Azure, which path should give to create ".credential" file

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm new to Azure, I'm just following this article's this section **[Deploying secrets to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure)**

so in Azure Cloud Shell I just type the following code and

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
  [String]$Name,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [String]$Password)

$credPath = $PSScriptRoot + '\' + $Name + ".credential"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString –String $Password –AsPlainText -Force 
$Credential = New-Object –TypeName `
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $Name, $PWord
$Credential | Export-CliXml $credPath
```

[image]

then for Name I type **testName** and for password typed **testPassword**. then after **$credPath** its ask me to enter path, I just typed following paths none of them are working

1. C:\Users\Projects -local path
2. ./Scripts
3. https://kelumtestkeyvault.vault.azure.net/ - Azure KeyValut Path

but I'm getting the same error as following

> Export-Clixml: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the
> argument 'https://kelumtestkeyvault.vault.azure.net/'

[image]

which path should I give here?

Comment: What happens when you just use `$credPath`? Something like `Export-CliXml -Path $credPath`.

Comment: Btw, if you just use `$PSScriptRoot` on the command line it's going to be blank/null. It only had a value when it's inside a script/module file (and you execute said script)... So typing it manually will be invalid

Comment: And the path to give is the path where you want it to save the file. Your last example does not work because you are providing two positional arguments ($credPath *and* https://...vault.azure.net) but only one is allowed and it should be a file path to write the xml file to. The purpose of this xml file is to be passed into **the next script in their example**. So pick a path to save it to and then use that path as argument to the next script. Although it's not clear exactly what you mean to do, as there are much easier ways to add secrets and such to keyvault

Comment: Also note that even though the path is meant for the next script in their documentation, they have conveniently left out the definition of the `GetCredsFromFile` command. So their example is quite incomplete. You may have to fish through the additional resources to find it (looks like they have a download for a possibly complete example)

Comment: @GauravMantri with that I'm gettin this `PS /home/kelum> $Credential | Export-CliXml $credPath
Export-Clixml: Access to the path '/testName.credential' is denied.`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I just tried without `PS /home/kelum> $Credential | Export-CliXml https://kelumtestkeyvault.vault.azure.net/` and getting `Export-Clixml: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I'll check further make this work thnx all

Comment: You can't pass the vault name as the parameter. It wants a file name.